# Simply save time as UTC with Django

Tags: python, django, timezone

I get a timestamp (via an extern API). When I try to save that, it always is two hours earlier.

I read some docs like [Django Time zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/), [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) and [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) but I still don't understand how to tell Django that this specific time should not be converted to UTC because it already is UTC.

It looks like this:

```
t = '2020-05-29 08:47:39' # this is UTC

MyModel(
    timestamp=t,
    …
).save()
```

In the database it is stored as `2020-05-29 06:47:39`. So it is shown on a template e. g. as `2020-05-29 08:47:39` whereas `2020-05-29 10:47:39` would be correct.

**settings.py**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution by myself: the string `t` must be converted to a datetime-object *including* the UTC timezone like this:

```
>>> t = '2020-05-29 08:47:39'

>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 29, 8, 47, 39)

>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.utc.localize(dt)

>>> tz
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 29, 8, 47, 39, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Saving this with Django, everything is perfect.